# Definition of a struct with a field name "use" error

Tags: rust

I'm trying to Deserialize a json response into a struct

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Jwks {
    alg: String,
    kty: String,
    use: String,
    n: String,
    e: String,
    kid: String,
    x5t: String,
    x5c: String
}
```

But it seems that the `use` keyword is reserved and cannot be used as a struct field name. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Sure, for example `#[serde(rename = "use")] _use: String`, see [docs](https://serde.rs/variant-attrs.html#rename)

Comment: I think that naming the attribute `r#use` (a [raw identifier](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/compatibility/raw_identifiers.html)) should work too, but it's not as convenient as renaming in serde.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a custom name with [rename](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#rename). Like this:

```
#[serde(rename = "use")]
s_use: String,
```

Here is a complete example with your struct:

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Jwks {
    alg: String,
    kty: String,
    #[serde(rename = "use")]
    s_use: String,
    n: String,
    e: String,
    kid: String,
    x5t: String,
    x5c: String
}
```